# Getting an ArrayTypeMismatchException with an array of objects

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am writing a *very simple* method to convert a csv to a datatable so it can be inserted into a SQL database. It works exactly how it should, unless I try to replace empty strings with DBNull.Value, then it throws an ArrayTypeMismatchException. The stream coming in is a simple comma-separated file with the data.

The problem code:

```
public static DataTable StreamToTable(Stream stream, bool headersAvailable, bool convertBlankToDBNull)
    {

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        if (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            if (headersAvailable)
            {
                try
                {
                    //get headers from first line
                    string[] headers = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');

                    //construct headers
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        data.Columns.Add(headers[i]);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ioEx)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                object[] row = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');

                if (convertBlankToDBNull)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (row[i].ToString().Equals(""))
                        {
                            row[i] = DBNull.Value; //this is where I get the exception
                        }
                    }
                }
                data.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return data;
        }
        else return null;
    }
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong... I should be able to assign anything to the array because it's an object array, so how can there be a type mismatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've discovered the horrors of [unsafe array covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

`row` is a `string[]` that has been unsafely cast to `object[]`.  Even though that cast succeeds, the array is still a `string[]` (since that's what `Split()` returns), and cannot be *used* as an `object[]`.
In particular, it still can't hold things that aren't `string`s.

Instead, you can create a new `object[]` and populate it with those `string`s:

```
object[] row = Array.ConvertAll(
    reader.ReadLine().Split(','),
    s => (object)s
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You have shown me something that will be very helpful in the future, as I am sure I will run into this again!

Comment: I was ready to hit my head against a wall on a similar problem.  This answer helped tremendously!  Thank you for help!!